Supabase: order parent and child in the same table by using supabase-js
Is there a way to order parent and child in the same table by using supabase-js?
I have a comments table.
create table
  public.comments (
    id uuid not null default gen_random_uuid (),
    created_at timestamp with time zone not null default now(),
    post_id uuid not null,
    user_id uuid not null default auth.uid (),
    parent_id uuid null,
    text text not null,
    constraint comments_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint comments_parent_id_fkey foreign key (parent_id) references comments (id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
    constraint comments_post_id_fkey foreign key (post_id) references posts (id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
    constraint comments_user_id_fkey foreign key (user_id) references profiles (id) on update cascade on delete cascade
  ) tablespace pg_default;

When retrieving data from this table, I want to order the comments such that parent comments appear before their child comments.
For example, given the following rows:
[{id: "a", parent_id: null}, {id: "b", parent_id: null}, {id: "c", parent_id: "a"}}]
I want the outcome to be:
[{id: "a", parent_id: null}, {id: "c", parent_id: "a"}, {id: "b", parent_id: null}}]
Please notice rows that are related to id a are ordered first and then the rest.
This is what I've coded so far:
const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from("comments")
      .select(`*, profiles(*)`)
      .eq("post_id", postId)
      .order("created_at", { ascending: false });

Is there a way to achieve the desired ordering using supabase-js? or Should I order on client side? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
